# will php listen for post request in a webpage?

Tags: php, post

will the  listen for post requests here too ? if so how can i get it to work ? and send post requests from the server side?

I'm trying to send a post requestfrom a the server using PHP, recevie it on the client side and change web pages dynamically..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
<? if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {echo "POST RECEIVED";} ?>
<? echo "OK";?>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.14.7/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Tried to send a post request like so: but it doesnt seem to echo

```
  $url = 'http://http://mysite/trial_page.php';
  $data = array('key1' => 'value1', 'key2' => 'value2');

// use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
  $options = array(
    'http' => array(
      'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
      'method'  => 'POST',
      'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
  );
```

Comment: $url is not a valid url and you must pass the $options array your building to something which will do the HTTP request

Comment: The client side does cannot receive http requests, only a server can do that

Comment: how can i work around this ?

Comment: Work around what? As the first comment says, if you actually _send_ the request as well as just building it, you should be fine. You'll also need to have your calling code actually read the response as well, to know what was echoed

Comment: im sorry i got confused with : The client side does cannot receive http requests, only a server can do that: so if I receive a post request like this, can I make change to elements on the HTML ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. Http is simple - you send a http request from somewhere to a webserver. The webserver processes the request and sends back a response to wherever the request came from. If that response happens to contain html then, yes, naturally the server can influence the content of it before it returns it to the requestor.

Comment: But...I wonder...are you actually asking how to change the content of a page which is already loaded into someone's browser? I am trying to think of a reason for the way you worked your question. That is a rather different scenario from the basic http request-response model, though.

Comment: i think im too much of a noob that I don't even know what to ask for ! I'm sorry..

Comment: Well, can you describe in more general terms what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: i have two pages: An activator and and a monitor. I have someJS that changes the CSS of elements on the page in the activator (OnClick). When this change happens, I want for it to reflect on the monitor page, live, without refresh. This activator page, does not require a login, but the monitor page does. I want for the changes to show up to all users that are on the monitor page..

Comment: Ok so a page which is already running in a browser is a client-side thing. You cannot send a HTTP request to it directly - it's not a server. You need a way for the two pages to communicate _via_ a webserver. Firstly, when the JS code runs in the "activator" page you need to send a HTTP request to your webserver, to tell it that the change has occurred (and include details of the change, presumably). I'm assuming you don't want to refresh the page and lose the CSS changes you just made, so it's probably best to send the request asynchronously using JS & AJAX.

Comment: Then your server needs to store the information it just received - a database would be a logical place to put it - in such a way that it's possible to understand what happened, when it happened, and (if applicable) who the information is intended for.

Comment: Then the next thing is that the message needs to get to the monitor page. This is where it gets interesting. As discussed above, using standard HTTP you cannot send a message to a web page in a browser. However that doesn't mean it can't receive information - you've no doubt seen many sites which can display new information dynamically while you're still on the page. There are various ways you can approach this.

Comment: These approaches start from the simplest one with the worst user experience, up to the most complex one with the best experience. So it's a tradeoff you need to decide on, in terms of the effort you're prepared to make to implement it, vs the level of experience you actually need for your project - i.e. a cost/benefit analysis. This is especially relevant if you have little/no experience in implementing the solutions, since you'll need to factor in your own abilities and the learning curve too.

Comment: 1) The crudest and simplest way is to set a `<meta` tag which causes the page to auto-refresh at fixed intervals. This would mean the page is refreshed from the server (and presumably therefore, if its content is generated by PHP code, contains the latest info when refreshed). 2) The next best way is to use setInterval() in JS to cause a function to run at fixed intervals, which sends an AJAX request to the server to fetch the latest data, and then updates the page based on the response it receives. This is asynchronous and doesn't refresh the whole page, but...

Comment: ...it's not fully real-time (since you have to wait for each interval) and also it scales badly - if you make the time interval too frequent and/or there are too many users viewing the monitor page, you will overload your server and crash it. The last approach 3) is to re-design the structure entirely using WebSockets. This allows fully real-time communication, because there's a 2-way channel opened between browser and server, so the browser can directly send info to the browser whenever you need it to.

Comment: You would need a websocket server running alongside (or integrated into) your webserver, and then the activator and monitor pages would both need open websocket connections loaded into them, connecting to your websocket server. In this design the activator page would send the message to the server via the socket connection, and the server would immediately relay that message on to the monitor page, which would receive and act on it almost instantly. So it's much more real-time and efficient but there's a very significant amount of extra knowledge and work required to get it up and running.